# Unable to Map JSON to Java bean

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, resttemplate

I am getting error:

`Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of com.zee.FilterVO out of START_ARRAY token.  at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@1b54362; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: : Can not deserialize instance of com.zee.FilterVO out of START_ARRAY token`

**Java call to get JSON:**

```
ResponseEntity<FilterVO> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, FilterVO.class);
```

**Java Bean to Map JSON:**

```
public class FilterVO {

    private String userName;
    private String expirationTime;
    private String lastMatchedTime;
    private String state;
    private Integer matchedTodayCount;
    private Boolean useRegEx;
    private List<String> matchStrings;
    private List<String> hosts;
    private String activationTime;
    private String objectId;
    private String description;
    public Map<String, String> nameValuePairs;

    getters and setters....
}
```

**JSON what I am suppose to get:**

```
[{
    "userName": "Z111111",
    "expirationTime": "2015-03-15T14:00:00.000-0400",
    "activationTime": "1969-12-31T19:00:00.000-0500",
    "hosts": ["aa", "bb"],
    "matchStrings": [" aa is not running", " bb is not running"],
    "useRegEx": false,
    "nameValuePairs": {
        "KEY VALUE": "asasa",
        "PROGRAM": "dsds",
        "REGION": "dfsffs"
    },
    "objectId": "SOMEID:20141015140803579-802",
    "matchedTodayCount": 190,
    "lastMatchedTime": "2015-03-09T07:53:20.366-0400",
    "state": "ACTIVE",
    "description": "Blah Blah Blah..."
}]
```

> Initially I thought I am facing this issue because of deserialization of one element Array. So I modified my java code.

```
private void getFilter() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = getCustomRestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.set("access-token", getAccessToken());
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
        ResponseEntity<FilterVO> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, FilterVO.class);
}

private RestTemplate getCustomRestTemplate() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);     
        MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        messageConverters.add(messageConverter);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
        return restTemplate;
}
```

**Still I am getting the same error.**

I am having the following `jackson` jars in my classpath:

```
jackson-annotations-2.5.1.jar
jackson-core-2.5.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-databind-2.5.1.jar
jackson-datatype-joda-2.5.1.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
```

Full STACK Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of com.zee.FilterVO out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@bc5596; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.zee.FilterVO out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@bc5596; line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.read(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:171)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:693)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:679)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:496)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:465)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:416)
    at com.fidelity.selfservice.test.JMagicRestAPI.getFilter(JMagicRestAPI.java:63)
    at com.fidelity.selfservice.test.JMagicRestAPI.main(JMagicRestAPI.java:46)
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.zee.FilterVO out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream@bc5596; line: 1, column: 1]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:219)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:212)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializer.java:875)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1923)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:176)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: What about Map, if you delete it does it work?

Comment: Removed `Map`, still same error

Comment: Is your `restTemplate.exchange` method reading the complete response properly? Is the server flushing the whole response at the end of response processing cycle?

Comment: exchange method is working fine. I am getting data if I use String, i.e `ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);`

Comment: `nested exception is org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException` it would be helpful to know what that Exception was. The lowest Exception is the root and has to be provided to resolve an error.

Comment: Could be the `mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);` line

Comment: @sturcotte06 , Nope, I am getting error without that also.

Comment: Well the exception clearly state it could not DESERIALIZE your object. It's not a problem with serialization, but with deserialization. I think your code does not do what you think it does. Also, he's clearly looking for an array, and he must've had a POJO json.

Comment: @sturcotte06 Well the posted `JSON` is what I am getting when I use, `ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);` , so I am getting a `JSON` and I can see the `JSON` format, Is there issue in my java bean class?

Comment: Well the exception occurs after that. Something in your code tries to deserialize the json.

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach [Full Stack Trace](http://www.codeshare.io/gCgLP)

Comment: Have you tried adding `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` to the `FilterVO` class  ?

Comment: @jny That also doesn't work, same error.

Comment: Try to deserialize the String gained from `ResponseEntity<String>` via `mapper.readValue(responseEntity.getString(), FilterVO.class)` does this work? If not, create an instance of FilterVO, fill it with values and serialize that with `writeValueAsString(Object value)`- there should be a difference between the JSON strings!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're getting a JSON array, but you're trying to deserialize that JSON with a POJO, `FilterVO` in your case.

Try changing this line:

```
ResponseEntity<FilterVO> responseEntity = 
    restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, FilterVO.class);
```

by this one:

```
ResponseEntity<List<FilterVO>> responseEntity = 
    restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, 
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<FilterVO>>() {});
```

Now you'll have a `List<FilterVO>` to work with.

Comment: The posted JSON he resolves is no array, but perhaps he made a copy paste failure; we'll see :)

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach sure, but the stacktrace indicates that an array is being sent back.

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach I am getting JSON array. Missed the Square brackets. :(

Comment: Than Magnamag found the answer. Don't forget to accept and upvote it ;)

Comment: @Magnamag `TypeReference` doesn't work with spring `exchange` method, instead I have used `ParameterizedTypeReference`. Now its working fine. :)

Comment: @Zeeshan I'll fix it in my answer. Thank you!